# Is there a way to login to Nagios server from the backend and keep the session alive?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, nagios

I was told that Nagios supports basic authentication. 
But the following doesn't seem to work.
What should be done to authenticate and keep session alive?

```
    s = requests.Session()
    s.auth = ('username', 'password')
    result = s.get("www.nagios_server.com")
    print result.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that there is no need to do that. 
Nagios services can be accessed with username and ticket after configuring CGI accesses.